# In Django how do I call a function in the template

Tags: python, html, django

As you can see I am trying to create a function and use it in the template by calling it in the `get_context_data`

But when I refresh the page, it gives me the error: `name 'sidebar' is not defined`.

I think I might need to pass some variables into the `sidebarFunction` but I am not entirely sure.

HTML:

```
                    {% if user.is_staff %}
                        {% for client in sidebar %}
                            <li>
                                <!-- <a href="{% url 'public:client_detail' client.client.pk %}"> -->
                                <p class="client-title" onclick="subNavDropDown(this)">{{ client.client }}</p>
                                <!-- </a> -->
                            </li>
                            <ul class="sub-nav" id="{{ client.client }}-subnav">
                                {% for project in client.projects %}
                                <!-- Add a link to this -->
                                <li class="sub-nav" id="project-dropdown-{{ project.pk }}">
                                    {{ project }}
                                </li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <br>
                    {% else %}
                        {% for project in sidebar %}
                            <li>
                                <a href="{% url 'public:client_detail' client.pk %}">
                                    <p class="client-title"></p>{{ client }}</p>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
```

Python:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        client = self.request.user.groups.all()
        context["project"] = Project.objects.filter(client=self.get_object())
        context["projects"] = Project.objects.filter(client__in=client, active=True)

        context["sidebar"] = sidebar

        return context

    def sidebarFunction(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            sidebar = []
            for client in Client.objects.all():
                data = {
                    "client": client,
                    "projects": Project.objects.filter(client=client),
                }
                sidebar.append(data)
        else:
            sidebar = Project.objects.filter(client__in=client, active=True)
```

Comment: look at the line `context["sidebar"] = sidebar`. What is `sidebar` supposed to be here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is call the `sidebarFunction` inside your `get_context_data` and the values returned from your `sidebarFunction` will be available in the template.

```py
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    client = self.request.user.groups.all()
    context["project"] = Project.objects.filter(client=self.get_object())
    context["projects"] = Project.objects.filter(client__in=client, active=True)

    context["sidebar"] = self.sidebarFunction()

    return context


def sidebarFunction(self):
    sidebar = []
    data = {}

    if self.request.user.is_staff:
        for client in Client.objects.all():
            data.update({
                "client": client,
                "projects": Project.objects.filter(client=client),
            })
            sidebar.append(data)
    else:
        data.update({'projects': Project.objects.filter(client__in=client, active=True)})
        sidebar.append(data)

    return sidebar
```

Comment: the `sidebarFunction()` must also be changed to return the sidebar !

Comment: @MaxLoyd in your snippet, this functions creates a local variable "sidebar" but doesn't return it to the caller. You have to add "return sidebar" at the end of the function for the whole thing to work.

Comment: Thanks @brunodesthuilliers. Updated my answer